# an fm antenna plug I've never seen before

Tags: antenna

I just acquired a Sony STR DN1080 AVR, and the FM plug on it is not coaxial or anything else I've seen before. Does anyone know what it's called and if an adaptor to a standard coaxial F connector is available? (see photo):[image]

Comment: There a whole lot of connectors like that of varying metric pitches which are very hard to tell apart without a physical example for side by side comparison - JST-PH, etc.  Best bet is probably to try to find the manual online.

Comment: Can you find a way to measure the pitch of that connector?

Comment: to connect a coaxial you'll need a balun

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what the pitch of a connector is. And I've located the manual and it doesn't have anything to say about it; just how to plug it in and lay out the antenna. If I take a photo of the thing next to a measuring stick would that help? It's really very small, perhaps only 3 mm.